# Redirect to login page after session expiry - Python Flask App

Tags: python, timeout, flask-login

I have a python flask app with login module implemented using extension python flask. In my login method, I have set below

```
def login():
   .......
   .......
   session.permanent = True
   app.permanent_session_lifetime = datetime.timedelta(minutes=3)
   ......
   ......
```

This code sets my session cookie to 3 minutes as expected.

What's happening right now is, after 3 minutes, the page is still active and  sending GET requests and POST request even the session is expired. What I want is after session is expired the page to default to login page.

Does flask-login provides this functionality out of box? Any suggestion would be helpful

Thanks

Comment: Did you any solution to this issue? I am looking for same

Comment: Nope, I didn't solved this issue.It's still open for me.Since it's a hobby project, I left it like that and moved to other things.

Comment: did you try following answer. It worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Using flask-login, do this, it will automatically redirects to login page.

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
     flask.session.permanent = True
     app.permanent_session_lifetime = datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)
     flask.session.modified = True
```